# Python: Calculate Net Reclassification Index (NRI) and Integrated Discrimination Improvement (IDI) from logistic regression models

Tags: python

How to calculate Net Reclassification Index (NRI) and Integrated Discrimination Improvement (IDI) from logistic regression models at differnt thresholds using Python? Are there any existing functions?

I am trying to get NRI value along with 95% CI) as well as IDI.